# Can't use axios.get on fleek

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I have a project on NextJS and solidity, on localhost `axios.get` is working fine but not on fleek it's not. I will share the code as well as the github repo below

On localhost working fine
[image]

On fleek
[image]

https://github.com/ashu26jha/web3drivefrontend

The below code is just of components Cards.. axios.get is not working anywhere

```
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Cards({ ipfs, tokenId }) {
    
    function handleClick() {
        localStorage.setItem("Index Clicked", tokenId);
        document.getElementById("hideNavbar").style.display = 'flex';
    }

    const [imageHash, setImageHash] = useState(ipfs);
    const [name,setName] = useState(null);
    async function updateUI(){
        console.log(ipfs);
        await axios.get(`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${ipfs}`)
            .then(function (response) {
                setImageHash(response.data.imageHash)
                setName(response.data.name)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    if(ipfs){
        updateUI();
    }

    let extension = ""
    
    if(name!=null){
        extension = name.slice(name.indexOf('.') + 1,);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="card select" onClick={handleClick}>
            <div class="top-left"></div>
            <div className="extension">{extension}</div>
            <div className="name">{name}</div>
            {imageHash ? <div className="ipfs">IPFS: {imageHash.slice(0, 4)}...{imageHash.slice(40,)}</div> : <div>Hash unavailable..</div>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Basically I have to get a `JSON` file and use some data. If there exist a method except `axios` please do suggest....